# How do i get text for each <li> tag under the same div class using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, html-lists, nokogiri, screen-scraping

I am scraping ingredients of a recipe with Nokogiri (HTML/CSS). Each ingredient is in an li under an ingredient div. Right now my code is collecting all the ingredients without separation in a string. How can I get each li text into an array?

The site has this

```
<div class="easyrecipe">
 <div class="ingredients">
  <ul>
   <li class="ingredient" itemprop="recipeIngredient"> 1 tbsp flax</l>
   <li class="ingredient" itemprop="recipeIngredient"> 3 tbsp water</l>
   <li class="ingredient" itemprop="recipeIngredient"> ½ cup spelt</l>
  </ul>
```

i tried this to try to parse it and get the ingredients into an array

```
ingredients = page.css("div.easyrecipe").each do |section|
      section.css("li.ingredient").text
```

I am getting this
"1 tbsp ground flax3 tbsp warm water½ cup spelt"

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your list of ingredients is within `div.ingredients` which is inside `div.easyrecipe`.

Second, you're just printing all of the list text out for each section. Instead of adding the text of each section. You want to add the text of each ingredient.

I would instead change it to:

```
ingredients = page.css("div.easyrecipe").each do |section|
  section.css("li.ingredient").each do |ingredient|
    ingredient.text
```

Resulting in:

```
p ingredients
= ["1 tbsp ground flax","3 tbsp warm water","½ cup spelt"]
```